# How to resolve 'object null is not iterable' error while making prediction using tensorflow js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow.js

I was trying to make a sequence classifier using tf.js as a project. I trained a tensorflow.keras model on the data and converted the model to tfjs as below:

```
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(model, './')
```

Then, I uploaded it into my javascript using the following code:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';


var model = null;
async function loadModel() {
    model = await tf.loadLayersModel('assets/model/model.json');
    console.log('Loaded')
}
loadModel();
```

I developed a function to make predictions. Code for the same is:

```
async function pred() {
    tens = tf.zeros([batchSize, sentenceLength]);
    const preds = await model.predict(tens);
    return preds;
}
```

When I call pred() function it raises the following error:

```
TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```

I can tell that the error happened in model.predict() line, but I am not able to debug this. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**
It seems that the cause of the error was the following tag in *index.html* file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

When I removed this line, the error got resolved.

Comment: And you call `pred()` after the model has loaded? (after `await tf.loadLayersModel()` inside the load function)

Comment: Yes, I have successfully logged the model into console before calling pred() function.